# Skip already-installed packages in "yum install"?

Tags: yum

It seems that if a package is already installed, "yum install" will try to update it to the latest version. This will cause "yum install" to fail if the latest version is missing dependencies. I know that I can suppress this with `--skip-broken`, but I don't want to "skip broken" in case of packages which are not already installed; in that case I want it to fail.

I have seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12806200/191761) that I can do this using an "if" statement if I am installing just one package, but I have a "yum install" statement containing some 15 packages, and don't want to run `yum` multiple times (once for each package) as this adds a lot of overhead.

How can I get `yum` to only install packages if they are not already present?

Answer (score 3):

In the end I wrote a simple bash script `yum-install-if-missing.sh` based on other answers. Not sure if there is an easier way.

```
#!/bin/bash

yumcmd="yum install -y"
for var in "$@"
do
    if ! rpm --quiet --query $var; then
        yumcmd="$yumcmd $var"
    fi
done

echo "ABOUT TO EXECUTE: $yumcmd"

eval $yumcmd
```

It can then be executed as: `yum-install-if-missing.sh packageone packagetwo` and so on.

Comment: Use `rpm -q --quiet packagename` rather than piping to grep.

Comment: @Wildcard thanks! this really helped me. because I was running `yum-install-if-missing.sh ... file ...` and while `file` was not installed, `file-libs` was installed, so `file` got skipped. your suggestion fixed this problem